# How to get piecewise linear function in Python

Tags: python, piecewise

I would like to get piecewise linear function from set of points. Here is visual example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,7,9,11]
y = [2,5,9,1,11]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: piecewise illustration]

So I need a function that would take two lists and would return piecewise linear function back. I do not need regression or any kind of least square fit.

I can try to write it myself, but wonder if there is something already written. So far, I only found code returning regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try np.interp. It interpolates the values.

Here is a small example.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = [1,2,7,9,11]
>>> y = [2,5,9,1,11]

>>> np.interp([1.5, 3], x, y)
array([ 3.5,  5.8])
```

A caution note is to make sure for the sample points, make sure the x increases.

Comment: Well done, interpolation totally fell off the back of my mind.