# Beginner - Find in which "district" a point is located

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, logic

I use a NumPy library in Python and I have an exercise as follows:

Let's admit a map (a false one) with both `x` and `y` axes going from 0 to 1, representing 1 `Km²` of territory. Each point is an individual and it is placed on this map using normalized coordinates.

There is also a frontier separating the map into two "districts". This is not a straight one, and it must pass through A/B/C/D points, which are :

```
A = (0., 0.3711257)
B = (0.496042,0.62673)
C = (0.781478,0.510147)
D = (1.,0.73035714)
```

One part of the exercice is to know in which district any new point is located.

Obviously, I cannot just make a condition to compare the coordinates of an individual with `A-B-C-D`, but I don't know what I can do.

I'll be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that any two defined points on the frontier are conceptually connected by a straight line which essentially defines the location of the frontier between those points?

Comment: If either the `x` or `y` coordinates are sorted in any given scenario, you can define a piecewise linear function (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953030/how-to-get-piecewise-linear-function-in-python) ) and then check for new points whether they lie above or below that function. If neither of the coordinates are sorted, this appears to be not such an easy problem, I think.

Comment: @Jonathan > You are right, there is a straight line between AB, BC, etc.

Comment: @TKAcc, The problem partly depends on one how general you want the frontier to be. For example, could the shape have protuberances with bulges on the tips of the protuberances? Also, do you consider the territory delineated by the frontier to be a single space or might there be multiple spaces in the territory? I>E Could the territory have 3 spaces?

Comment: @Jonathan > Hi again. Something simple like that : https://i.imgur.com/cMRZ7ZA.png Only two territories separated by said frontier which is just a line, nothing more.